# Saving object or object Id in sharedPreference or SQL

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

In my grocery app,I was saving products selected by users in Singleton Class.Now according to new requirement, these products(cart) should be retrieved again whenever user reopens the app.
Class Product has many fields :

```
{
        "imageDisplay",
        "categorySpecial",
        "_id",
        "name_ch",
        "name_en",
        "origin_ch",
        "origin_en",
        "description_ch",
        "description_en",
        "specification_ch",
        "specification_en",
        "unit_ch",
        "unit_en",
        "priceOriginal",
        "price",
        "stock",
        "sold",
        "isOnShelf",
        "processingPriority",
        "imageCover"
}
```

1) My First question is should I just be saving all product field or just product Id.In case, if I save product Ids,I will have to retrieve detail of all cart products when app starts ,but If I save all fields of product then it will occupy a lot of memory.

Which one is the preferred way to save products?

There are 3 options as per my knowledge
1) storing in shared Preference
2) storing in File
3) storing in sql

Comment: use gson library to save your object in shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a simple SQLite Database. Since you only need to store grocery items, I don't think you would need more than one table with 2-3 rows. Android has pretty good documentation on it. If you have any struggles with it you can ask here or see some step-by-step tutorials.

Android documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing Products in SQLite database better decision will be to store product ids in SharedPreferences. To retrieve products cart you first obtain ids from SharedPreferences and then find your products by that ids. Imagine the situation when product options changed - you will required to change both SharedPreferences and Database product instances stored, so just storing id's will be better decision.

Answer (score 0):

To retain the state of an app upon app death, SharedPreferences is to be used. If you need a database, you can use SQLite.

For your intention, SharedPreferences is the best as all you need do is to retain what the user sees before killing the app. Hence, all you need concern yourself are those fields in your data that are presented to the user (those data that users sees or interact with before killing your app) one of which may be id or origin_ch.

For database you need all necessary data saved but for SharedPreferences, you need only the data the user sees or interact with before the app death.